# Resample dataframe using maximum of only one column while retaining other features at that maximum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this code,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


d= {'Date': ['2019-10-21 00:05:00','2019-10-21 00:10:00','2019-10-21 00:15:00',
'2019-10-21 00:20:00','2019-10-21 00:25:00'],'Hi_Speed': [37.0,30.6,38.6,37.0,38.6],
'Hi_Dir': [67.5,90.0,90.0,90.0,67.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(arg =df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:M:%S',infer_datetime_format=True)
```

I have a dataframe as follows

```
                     Date  Hi_Speed  Hi_Dir
0     2019-10-21 00:05:00      37.0    67.5
1     2019-10-21 00:10:00      30.6    90.0
2     2019-10-21 00:15:00      38.6    90.0
3     2019-10-21 00:20:00      37.0    90.0
4     2019-10-21 00:25:00      38.6    67.5
```

I wish to resample it at a period of 10 minutes to retain the maximum Hi_Speed   while retaining the associated Hi_Dir as shown below.

```
                    Date  Hi_Speed  Hi_Dir
0     2019-10-21 00:10:00      37.0    67.5
1     2019-10-21 00:20:00      38.6    90.0
```

Please note that my actual dataframe has more than 16k records and I will be sampling at 1 hour period.

Comment: do you want to retain the max Hi_Speed as a reference for adding/substracting 10 min from that row?

Comment: I wish to do a resampling at a period of 10 min using the maximum value Hi_Speed  only but I also want to keep the value of Hi_Dir at that maximum value of Hi_Speed .

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


d= {'Date': ['2019-10-21 00:05:00','2019-10-21 00:10:00','2019-10-21 00:15:00', '2019-10-21 00:20:00','2019-10-21 00:25:00'],
    'Hi_Speed': [37.0,30.6,38.6,37.0,38.6],
    'Hi_Dir': [67.5,90.0,90.0,90.0,67.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(arg =df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:M:%S',infer_datetime_format=True)

df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)

speed_idxmax = df.resample('10T', origin='2019-10-21 00:00:00')[['Hi_Speed']].idxmax()['Hi_Speed']

df = df.resample('10T', origin='2019-10-21 00:00:00').sum().assign(Hi_Speed=df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Speed'].values,
                                                                   Hi_Dir=df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Dir'].values)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
# print(df)

                 Date  Hi_Speed  Hi_Dir
0 2019-10-21 00:00:00      37.0    67.5
1 2019-10-21 00:10:00      38.6    90.0
2 2019-10-21 00:20:00      38.6    67.5
```

Let's elaborate what's happening with

```py
df.resample('10T', origin='2019-10-21 00:00:00')[['Hi_Speed']].idxmax()
```

- `.resample('10T', origin='2019-10-21 00:00:00')`

  - I will talk about `origin` later.
  - `10T` means downsampling the pandas into 10 minute bins
- `[['Hi_Speed']].idxmax()` gets the index of maximum `Hi_Speed` value in each bin and records that in `Hi_Speed` column.

Then is

```py
df.resample('10T', origin='2019-10-21 00:00:00').sum().assign(Hi_Speed=df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Speed'].values,
                                                              Hi_Dir=df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Dir'].values)
```

- `.sum()` just converts `DatetimeIndexResampler` type to `Dataframe`. it could be anything that does the same thing like `.mean()`
- `.assign(Hi_Speed=df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Speed'].values)`

  - `df.loc[speed_idxmax]` gets rows with maxiumn `Hi_speed` values.
  - `df.loc[speed_idxmax]['Hi_Speed'].values` get `Hi_Speed` values from `df.loc[speed_idxmax]`.

Let's talk about the `origin` argument of [pandas.DataFrame.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). It could be an enum value from `{‘epoch’, ‘start’, ‘start_day’}` or a customize value of type `Timestamp` or `str`, default is `start_day`.

- `epoch`: origin is 1970-01-01
- `start`: origin is the first value of the timeseries
- `start_day`: origin is the first day at midnight of the timeseries